# Center embedded audio posts on Tumblr

Tags: tumblr, html, css

On my Tumblr blog I'm trying to center the embedded audio posts but they won't. I found some other people have tried centering iFrame. 
I've also tried setting `margin: auto;` in the CSS inside `.audioembed`

Here's my block audio code:

```
.audioEmbed {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

{block:Audio}
  {block:AudioEmbed}

    <div class="audioEmbed">
      {AudioEmbed-400}
    </div>

  {/block:AudioEmbed}
{/block:Audio}
```

How can I get embedded audio posts to show centered on a post?

Answer (score 1):

In order to center a block-level element you need to give it a width. It will otherwise default to 100%.

```
.audioEmbed {
    width: 20em;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```